# How can I run a .bin file from the same file inside .iso

Tags: c, assembly, bootloader

I apologize in advance for the bad language, I mainly use a Google translator.
I decided to do something like my OS (naturally, it will just be "Hello World").  I have a bootloader file containing the following code and inside the .iso file:

```
org 7C00h
cli
hang:
jmp hang
times 510-($-$$) db 0
db 0x55
db 0xAA
```

How can I make sure that after executing the bootloader, I will run another .bin file, for example, kernel.bin?
And also, can I write C code, compile it as a .bin file and somehow run it in my "OS"?

Comment: I recommend you take a tour around [the OSDev Wiki](https://wiki.osdev.org/Main_Page). It have all information you need (in English), including tutorials. There are also *many* other resources about boot-loaders and kernel loading and programming, all over the Internet. Please use your favorite search engine to find more.

Comment: Believe me, I really searched already many different sources in several languages. But the information on the question I need is simply catastrophically small.

Comment: Your title talks about an ISO file (do you mean an ISO 9660 CD image)?  Booting from CD is an entirely different task that involves building an El Torito boot catalogue.  Unless that is what you want to do, consider editing the title to remove mentions of ISO images.

Comment: Note that “after executing the bootloader, I will run another .bin file” is not how it works.  It's the job of your bootloader to load and execute further code.  There is no automatism to do that; you have to load the code from disk yourself and then jump to it, optionally after relocating the boot loader.

Comment: fuz, By "iso" I mean the disk image .iso. The bootloader runs quietly on VirtualBox, but I'm interested in how to launch other files after starting the bootloader.

Comment: @HomaX Do you mean a hard disk image or is it a CD image?  If it's a hard disk image, `.iso` is an uncommon file extension.  As I said before: to launch other files, load them from disk in your bootloader and then jump to the code's entry point.  You have to do that yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting with a *floppy* image is much simpler for beginners.

Don't think about a file-system or attempting to load from a file-system yet, just create a single binary blob that you write to a floppy-image.

Create the binary blob with the boot-loader, then append the kernel itself. The boot-loader can then just read the remaining sectors of the floppy into memory, and then make an absolute jump to the kernel image.

The kernel image is itself a binary blob, whose first location is assembly instructions to set up stack etc., and then call the kernels `main` function.

---

While creating your own boot-block and kernel-loader is a good exercise, my suggestion is to only use it as a stepping-stone and learning exercise.

Once you have done it and it works, then my recommendation is that you use an existing working boot-loader, like for example [GRUB](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/).

Using e.g. GRUB you can concentrate on the kernel side.